# Как печатать картинку в csv через php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

Здравствуйте, сделал скрипт который печатает в php и делает в csv формат.
Так вот задаюсь вопросом, как реализовать загрузку изображений в csv через php.

Вариант - вставить тег html не прошёл :(

Вот мой код:

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed

$filename = "basket_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array(' ID модели ', ' Имя модели ', ' Фамилия модели ', ' День рождения ', ' Месяц рождения ', ' Год рождения ', ' Рост ', ' Мобильный телефон ', ' Контактное лицо ',  ' Профиль модели(Фото и подробная инфо.) '));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
mysql_select_db('');
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT user.id, user.name, user.surname, user.day, user.month, user.year, user.height, user.phone_mob, user.contact, basket.user
        FROM user
        INNER JOIN basket
        ON user.id = basket.user
        ORDER BY basket.id;");

          // loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
    if (isset($row['user']))
    {
        $row['user'] = 'http://site.com/models?id='.$row['user'];
    }
    if ($row['name'] == '')
    {
        $row['name'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['surname']== '')
    {
        $row['surname'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['day'] == '')
    {
        $row['day'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['month'] == '')
    {
        $row['month'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['year'] == '')
    {
        $row['year'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['height'] == '')
    {
        $row['height'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['phone_mob'] == '')
    {
        $row['phone_mob'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    if ($row['contact'] == '')
    {
        $row['contact'] = "(не указано)";
    }
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```

Comment: csv - это не совсем excel-формат

Comment: @vp_arth ошибся, прощу прощение, исправил

Comment: Ну так, csv - это сугубо текстовый формат. Comma Separated Values - значения, разделённые запятыми. Ни о каких картинках в нём речи быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов кодировать картинку в `base64`.

```
$fh = fopen('/my/tmp/file.csv');
$values['name'] = 'Kiran';
$values['image'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/my/file/path.jpg'));
fputcsv($fh, $fields);
```

Comment: Только что попробовал, но в csv вывелись разные символы :(

Comment: @MaximPoddubny как вы берете картинку? и примерно какого размера она?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, человек хочет открыть csv в Excel и увидеть картинку.

Comment: до 1 мб картинка, формат jpg

Comment: @vp_arth Автор сказал вот это в вопросе `как реализовать загрузку изображений в csv через php.`

Comment: @MaximPoddubny А можно узнать что означает ваша фраза `но в csv вывелись разные символы`

Comment: Сейчас печатает огромную строку символов такого вида /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1

Comment: @MaximPoddubny но я что то не понимаю? что вы хотели? посмотрите что делает `base64_encode`.http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php, Не пойму вы хотите картинку увидеть открыв текстовой файл?

Answer (score 0):

`CSV` - это сугубо текстовый формат.
`Comma Separated Values` - значения, разделённые запятыми.
Ни о каких картинках в нём речи быть не может.

Вам нужно собирать настоящий xls/xlsx.

Например, с помощью `PHPExcel`:

```
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
require_once('PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');

$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();

// Текст
$sheet->setCellValue("A1", 'Некий Текст');
// Картинка
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/picture.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A2');

// Вывод
header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=table.xls" );
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Пробую сделать то что вы написал, но не лепится файлик, если не сложно могли бы в скайпе помочь, я уже добавился если что

Comment: Нет, в скайпе не мог бы. И не пытайтесь форсировать общение вне контекста проекта - тут это не поощряется.

Comment: Понимаю, если что я уже постучался как в скайп так и вк.Просто совсем уже не понятно стало

Comment: @MaximPoddubny здесь для быстрого общения существует [система чатов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) к которой у вас скоро будет доступ

Comment: Я сделал все как вы описали, библу подключил, но не создается файла

Comment: Основа этого ответа в том, что вы пользуетесь неверным инструментом. Готового решения я давать и не планировал, просто привёл пример.